# Conditional compilation for Rust build.rs script?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

The Rust language supports [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) using attributes like `#[cfg(test)]`.
Rust also supports [build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) using a `build.rs` file to run code as part of the build process to prepare for compilation.

I would like to use conditional compilation in Rust code to conditionally compile depending on whether we're compiling for a build script, similar to how that is possible for `test` builds.

Imagine the following:

```rust
#[cfg(build)]
fn main() {
    // Part of build script
}

#[cfg(not(build))]
fn main() {
    // Not part of build script, probably regular build
}
```

This does not work, because `build` is not a valid identifier here.
Is it possible to do this using a different attribute, or could some other trick be used to achieve something similar?

---

For some context on this issue:
My goal is to generate shell completion scripts through `clap` at compile time. I've quite a comprehensive `App` definition across multiple files in the  application. I'd like to use this in `build.rs` by including these parts using the `include!(...)` macro (as [suggested](https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/struct.App.html#examples-47) by `clap`), so I don't have to define `App` a second time. This pulls some dependencies with it, which I'd like to exclude when used by the `build.rs` file as they aren't needed in that case. [This](https://github.com/timvisee/ffsend/blob/f51bd673ff60f9403260702a90a4f192e6f93538/src/cmd/handler.rs#L51) is what I'm trying to make available in my `build.rs` script.

Comment: *whether we're compiling for a build script* — this doesn't make sense. A build script is only contained within a special file (e.g. `build.rs`). There is no other context that it can be compiled in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll explain what situation I'd like to use it for: It's for generating shell completion scripts through `clap` at compile time. I've quite a comprehensive `App` definition across multiple files (in the main application). I want to pull this in in `build.rs` to generate the definitions. This pulls some dependencies with it, which I'd like to exclude when used by the `build.rs` file.

(what is suggested: https://docs.rs/clap/2.32.0/clap/struct.App.html#examples-47) (what I want to use: https://github.com/timvisee/ffsend/blob/master/src/cmd/handler.rs#L51)

Comment: *which I'd like to exclude when used by the build.rs file* — why? You will have to build these for the main application anyway

Comment: It requires me to define quite a few `dev-dependencies`. Along with that, it feels unnecessary include quite a lot of code that isn't covered in the `build.rs` script. I believe the script should be as simple as possible, without pulling in the whole main application. I'd like to refrain from defining `App` a second time, and want to prevent duplicate code.

Answer (score 2):

You can just put the build code in build.rs (or presumably have build.rs declare a mod xyz to pull in another file).

I wonder if the question you are trying to ask is whether you can reference the same code from build.rs and main.rs, and if so can that code tell if it's being called by one or the other. It seems you could switch on an environment variable set when using build.rs (using something like [`option_env`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.option_env.html), but possibly a nicer way might be to enable a feature in the main code from within build.rs.

(Have a read of [the documentation for build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) if you haven't already.)

Comment: You can enable feature at build time by putting following line `println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=feature=\"build-time\"")` into the `build.rs:main` for example. But the scope is different. It affects current crate only, not dependencies (see https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5499 for more info). Also if you enable feature in this way, it will be enabled in the build result (bin, lib) as well. So, it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: That's indeed one way of going about it, but it feels a little clunky. I'd prefer having an extra feature just for the `build.rs` script instead of the other way around. But I don't think there's a way to instruct the compiler to do so. Any logic in the `build.rs` script would only be evaluated after compiling it (and pulling in application sources).

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me:

```
fn main() {
  if std::env::var("PROFILE").unwrap() == "debug" {
    // Here I do something that is needed for tests
    // only, not for 'release'
  }
}
```

Comment: This checks an environment variable at runtime, and has nothing to do with conditional compilation.

Comment: @TimVisée well, it [works for me](https://github.com/objectionary/reo/blob/master/build.rs) exactly in compile time. Try to install this lib and you will see that `build.rs` is not executed (it takes at least a minute to run, while installation will be fast). However, if you check it out and do `cargo test`, the heavy part of `build.rs` will be executed. Maybe I misunderstood your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you'll get a warning and it might not be the best way to do this, you might have been looking for something along the lines of the following:

```rust
#[cfg(not(build))]
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=build");
}

#[cfg(build)]
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

When building this as a build script the `build` cfg option is not used so the first `main` function is ran.  The output tells cargo to add a cfg option to rustc called `build` whenever building this crate.  When the same file is then built as the bin target the `build` cfg option is turned on and hence the second main is the one that gets compiled.